# Why doesn't count increase or print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare

I am trying to create a Mastermind type game where a random sequence of numbers is produced and the player tries to guess the secret sequence.
I am trying to produce a way to compare lists at print how many letters in the player's guess are in the secret sequence. This code and other variations dont produce the desired result. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random 

numlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

blank_list = ['','','','']



def randomize_list(my_list):

    random.shuffle(my_list)
    newnumlist = my_list[0:4]
    print(newnumlist)
    return newnumlist

def player_input(this_list):
    player_list = []

    inp1 = input("Please input the first number in your sequence: " )
    this_list[0] = int(inp1)
    inp2 = input("Please input the second number in your sequence: ")
    this_list[1] = int(inp2)
    inp3 = input("Please input the first number in your sequence: " )
    this_list[2] = int(inp3)
    inp4 = input("Please input the second number in your sequence: ")
    this_list[3] = int(inp4)

    player_list = player_list + this_list
    
    print(player_list)
    return(player_list)

def guess_check(my_list, this_list):
    x = randomize_list(my_list)
    y = player_input(this_list)

    count = 0

    if x == y:
        print("Equal")

    while x != y:
        
        for i in range(0,4):
            if y[i] in x:
                count += 1
            else:
                continue
        
            print(count)   
                    

guess_check(numlist, blank_list)
```

Comment: Show us what the program _actually does_, and tell us how that's different from what you _expected_.

Comment: The intent of your program is hard to decipher.  One problem, perhaps, is that `len(my_list) == 8` and `len(this_list) == 4`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits But `randomize_list()` slices it to the first 4.

Comment: You're calling `player_input()` twice. You don't do anything with the first set of inputs, you only compare the second one. If you enter the correct numbers the second time, you'll get an `Equal` output.

Comment: @Barmar `newnumlist` is the sliced copy, which isn't used.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `return newnumlist`

Comment: @Barmar You're correct.  I was looking at `randomize_list(numlist)`.  I missed `randomize_list(my_list)`.

Comment: Just get rid of the calls to `randomize_list()` and `player_input()` that are outside the `guess_check()` function. You only need to do them inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

You never assign any value to the original list, you only change a copy of the list.

```
test = 'abc'


def function(test): #a copy of test is given to the function
    test = '123' #the copy is edited
    return test #the copy is returned


function(test) # the copy is just ignored
print(test)
```

The result will be **abc**

if you actually use the result

```
test = 'abc'


def function(test): #a copy of test is given to the function
    test = '123' #the copy is edited
    return test #the copy is returned


test = function(test) # the copy is just used to alter the original list
print(test)
```

The result will be **123**

Comment: `this_list[0] = int(inp1)` and so on assign values to the original list.